# UIImageView overlaps UILabel on next ViewController Open

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, swift3, uicollectionviewcell

I have a parent ViewController which opens a second one.
Second ViewController contains a grid view like in the image.

[image: Correct Image]

When I go back and enter same screen again I found layout changed to this

[image: Wrong Image]

Here in the second image, the UIImage overlaps the label.

Here is my InterfaceBuilder Settings

[image]

I change the size and EdgeInsets using following code

```
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAtIndexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
    let width = collectionView.frame.size.width/2 - 8*2
    if let cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: sizeForItemAtIndexPath) {
        return CGSize(width: width, height: cell.frame.height)
    } else {
        return CGSize(width: width, height: 104)
    }
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout: UICollectionViewLayout, insetForSectionAtIndex : NSInteger) -> UIEdgeInsets {
    return UIEdgeInsets(top: 8, left: 8, bottom: 8, right: 8);
}
```

Why do the first time only the layout is correct and after that the layout changes, Any Clues?

**Edit1:**

Here is a screen shot for 3d Debugging

[image: 3d debugging first open]

[image: 3d debugging second launch]

Comment: What is the output of cell.frame.height in  sizeForItemAtIndexPath ? Is that line hit every time ?

Comment: It is never hit!, Always set it as 104 for height

Comment: Have you tried 3d debugging to see what is going on on scene?

Comment: @NickCatib I have added 3d debugging screen shots.

Comment: you should rotate a bit so we can see what's behind :) thats the best part of 3d debugging

Comment: from comparison seems like label goes behind the image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to give `aspect ratio` constraint from UILabel to image. Hit and then run.
But before this make sure you did not want a static height for you `imageView`. If you want to the height of `imageView` to not be increase or decrease device wise then instead of aspect ratio just give a static `height constraint` to `imageView`. Your problem will be solve.

Answer (score 0):

try to set `clipToBounds` to true on your UIImageView in the xib file